# Android: Different methods in a fragment for different calling activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm currently writing an app to provide food information/a grocery list function. My current code uses a switch statement to determine which button (fruit, vegetables, etc.) was pressed and passes an array list to a fragment that is then displayed as a listview.

When its called by the information activity, users can click on items and be presented with a detail view. If the calling activity is the grocery list activity, users can swipe to add to an empty array list. Since the bulk of the code used is the same, is there a way to do this without using two separate fragments?

All I can think of is putting the activity hashcode in the bundle being passed 
to the fragment and using if statements to determine which activity passed the bundle (and thus which event listeners are used), but this doesn't seem like a very good solution to me.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the activity a fragment *is contained in*, or are you looking for the activity that started the activity that owns the fragment?

Comment: I'm looking for the activity that the fragment is contained in. I know I can use getActivity() to return the activity, but I was hoping to find some sort of unique identifier with which to identify the calling activity and then use that to determine which methods the fragment uses when called. The code used by each activity/fragment is very similar but not quite identical so I was hoping to find some way to reuse it rather than have it written twice.

Comment: `getActivity() instanceof ...` is quite unique. Or, you can use a String tag when adding the fragment to the container from the activity (see `FragmentTransaction.replace(container, fragment, tag)`) and then use `getTag()` from the fragment.